# I can't show the picture

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my source code.

---

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$datatamu=  mysql_query("select judul_gambar,nama_file from gambar order by judul_gambar asc");
echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>judul_gambar</th>
            <th>gambar</th>
        </tr>";
        while($rec=mysql_fetch_object($datatamu)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rec->judul_gambar."</td>";
        echo "<td";
        echo "<img src='.$rec->nama_file.' alt='.$rec->judul_gambar' title='.$rec->judul_gambar' width='100'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }"
    </table>";
        mysql_close();
?>
```

---

I'm creating a folder gambar on the same directory with the source code.
and here is the database

---

id_gambar:Int[5]

---

judul_gambar:varchar[25]

---

nama_file:varchar[25]

---

sorry if my english bad. :)

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I can't show the picture :)

Comment: Is the problem with the SQL bit ? Might be. It can be that you aren't getting the URL in the first place. Do a var_dump(object) and see if it prints the URL.

Comment: Use Mark Baker answer and check the path of the image url, May be you are passing only the filename of image

Comment: In your `while()` loop, try to do `var_dump($rec);` and see if you are getting the right data. Else, try to view-source your resulting HTML and see if they are actually referring to the correct image path.

Comment: the directory is wrong. I put . in front of the $rec-> filename
thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

In the echo statement, using `.` for concatenation when you're not concatenating means the `.` will appear in the echoed output

```
echo "<img src='".$rec->nama_file."' alt='".$rec->judul_gambar."' title='".$rec->judul_gambar."' width='100'>";
```

Comment: Look at the HTML that your script is generating and see what's actually produced by your code - learn to do this, and you're learning to debug your own code

Comment: the directory is wrong
I put **.** in front of the $ rec-> filename